# How can I get a hashtable as an array in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have an INI file, I print a setion as Hashtable. Can I get the each name and value of hashtable as an array?
This is my INI file when I print the hashtable.

```
Name                           Value                                              
----                           -----                                              
P1                             ABN,ABB,ABY                                        
S2                             AKS,AKE                                            
AS                             ABM,AC8,AKH                                        
JP                             ABJ,ACF                                            
RU                             ACB         
Function Location
{
    $FilePath = "C:\Users\xx\Documents\loc.ini"
    $section = "RegionMap"

    $store = "C:\Users\xx\Documents"
    $input_file = $FilePath
    $ini_file = @{}

    Get-Content $input_file | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Trim()
    } | Where-Object {


    $_ -notmatch '^(;|$)'
    } | ForEach-Object {
    if ($_ -match '^\[.*\]$') {
        $section = $_ -replace '\[|\]'
        $ini_file[$section] = @{}
    } else {
        $key, $value = $_ -split '\s*=\s*', 2
        $ini_file[$section][$key] = $value

    }
    }
       $Get_1 = $ini_file.($section)

    }
    return Location
```

### My Expectation

```
array[0] = P1    ABN,ABB,ABY 
array[1] = S2    AKS,AKE
```

Comment: why do you need it as an array, hastables are more useful than array when you have a key and values related to that key. Where are you going to use this ?

Comment: Converting straight to an array would be a problem because it is just a collection of strings. So you wouldn't be able to have it output the way you want, it would instead output as `P1,ABN,ABB,ABY`. What I think you are after is an array of objects.

Comment: Do you expect `P1    ABN,ABB,ABY` to be a string? If so just create that string from the hashtable... imo the fastest way in the current state

Answer (score 0):

you can also use List to get item using index. Here is the sample :

> ```
> $ini_file = @{} # your hastable ...  
> $list = New-Object Collections.Generic.List[String] # List
>
> $ini_file.Add("one",1); 
> $ini_file.Add("two",2); 
> $ini_file.Add("three",3);
>
> foreach( $k in $ini_file.Keys )
> {
>      $list.Add("$k `t $($ini_file[$k])")
> }
>
> $list[0]
> ```

The output will be :

> one              1

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it is not clear if you expect an array containing objects (keys and values) or just a string.
In case you are after enumerating the entries and keep the name/value pairs, you might consider to simply use the [`GetEnumerator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator?view=netframework-4.8) method and convert it into an array (by embedding it into `@(...)`):

```
$Array = @($HashTable.GetEnumerator())
$Array[2].Name
AS
$Array[2].Value
ABM,AC8,AKH
```

If you actually looking for a string, you can easily concatenate the name/value pairs in the result array on the fly:

```
$Array | ForEach-Object {"$($_.Name)`t$($_.Value)"}
P1      ABN,ABB,ABY
JP      BJ,ACF
AS      ABM,AC8,AKH
S2      AKS,AKE
RU      ACB
```

Besides, you can still search the array using the [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-6) cmdlet, e.g.:

```
$Array | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'AS'}

Name                           Value
----                           -----
AS                             ABM,AC8,AKH
```